# Выгрузка данных из Clickhouse в SQL Server через SSIS

Tags: sql-server, odbc, clickhouse, ssis

Пытаюсь выгрузить данные из Clickhouse (19.17.4.11) в SQL Server SSIS пакетом.
Установил на машине с Windows odbc-драйвер Clickhouse x32 версии 1.1.7, в ODBC Data Source Administrator настроил System DSN.
SSIS пакет создал в Visual Studio 2019. Для тестовых данных, очень простой пакет: Data Flow с ODBC Source (Clickhouse) ---> OLE DB Destination (SQL Server).
И в Source, и в Destination проблем нет. Таблицы видны, колонки видны, замапилось хорошо.
Но при запуске пакета - ошибка на первом шаге (Source):

Error: 0xC0014020 at Data Flow Task 1, ODBC Source [2]: SQLSTATE: HY000, Message: statement not prepared; 
Error: 0xC004701A at Data Flow Task 1, SSIS.Pipeline: ODBC Source failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC0014020.

Попробовал включить трейс odbc, там вот что:

DtsDebugHost    326c-2b74   EXIT  SQLFreeStmt  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HSTMT               0x07F05058
        UWORD                        0

DtsDebugHost    326c-2b74   ENTER SQLExecute 
        HSTMT               0x07F05058

DtsDebugHost    326c-2b74   EXIT  SQLExecute  with return code -1 (SQL_ERROR)
        HSTMT               0x07F05058

DIAG [HY000] statement not prepared (1)

До этого в трейсе естественно еще много всего, но вроде как ошибок нет.

Не пойму, что надо сделать, чтоб заработало.
Кто-нибудь настраивал успешно передачу данных Clickhouse <---> SQL Server через SSIS?

UPD: В SSIS пакете в "ODBC Source" превью работает. Данные из CL показываются.

Comment: 1. double-check ваш ODBC config, как описано - https://www.altinity.com/blog/2018/9/20/using-odbc-with-clickhouse (см 'Clickhouse-odbc Library') 2. что пишется в логи CH? (run command *sudo tail -n 128 /var/log/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.err.log*)

Comment: В логах CH 4 вот таких строки: <Warning> ConnectionPoolWithFailover: Connection failed at try №1, reason: Code: 32, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Attempt to read after eof (version 19.17.4.11)